# Deadlock on Select from table-valued parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

I have this piece of code which acquires connection from EF Core DB context
and executes select on the received data.

```cs
var conn = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection() as SqlConnection;
await conn.OpenIfNotAlreadyOpenAsync();

await conn.ExecuteAsync(@"select col2 from @Data",
new
{
    Data = data.AsTableValuedParameter("DataType")
});
```

The app is run as a .NET Core (3.1) Web API and uses SQL Server as a database.
Code is executed on each request to endpoint.
Everything is run locally, so there are no intervening operations on this Database.

When I execute a single request everything is fine.
When I execute **50 requests simultaneously**, I receive an exception:

```
Transaction (Process ID 106) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has
 been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
The statement has been terminated.
```

SQL profiler shows multiple `exec sp_reset_connection` statements, but no queries (at all).

[image]

Seems like each request fails there.

How is that possible, given that's only `SELECT`?
Shouldn't each request have its own temporary table?

Comment: You need to inspect the deadlock graph to see what resources are participating and how to resolve.

Comment: It's a temporary table, nothing else is writing there @MitchWheat.
Regarding the deadlock graph, I created it, but I don't see anything there:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjQTcaqIrcXSgQujcL5A26Rs5NcZ?e=x8AQoZ
Each transaction has its own 'Object lock'.

Comment: The deadlock graph has a lot of `GetInitializedIMA` - Googling that leads to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300740/self-deadlocked-process-on-a-table-variable and a comment there indicates CU13 for SQL Server 2019 has fixed some issues on this